# Disable CKEditor on Page Load

Tags: ckeditor

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to provide a WYSIWYG for one of the fields I am storing in the database.

There are records marked as deleted and so editing them is forbidden. I managed to disable all the input fields inside my form by adding the `disabled` attribute on the `fieldset` element. This approach however doesn't disable CKEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version this got implemented but on CKEditor 4 using

```
CKEDITOR.config.readOnly = true;
```

seems to solve the issue.